# Select non-equal value in SQL grouping

Tags: postgresql, group-by, case-when

I have a dataset of food eaten:

```
create table test
  (group_id integer,
  food varchar,
  item_type varchar);

insert into test values
  (764, 'apple', 'new_food'),

  (123, 'berry', 'new_food'),
  (123, 'apple', 'others'),
  (123, 'berry', 'others'),

  (86, 'carrot', 'others'),
  (86, 'carrot', 'new_food'),
  (86, 'banana', 'others');
```

In each group, the new food eaten is of `item_type` `new_food`. The previous food that was being eaten is whatever else in the group doesn't equal the `new_food`'s value.

The dataset I would like from this would be:

```
| group | previous_food | new_food |
------------------------------------
   764           null        apple
   123           apple       berry
    86           banana      carrot
```

However, I can't get the group selections correct. My attempt is currently:

```
select
  group_id,
  max(case when item_type != 'new_food' then food else null end) as previous_food,
  max(case when item_type = 'new_food' then food else null end) as new_food
from test
group by group_id
```

However, we can't rely on the `max()` function to pick the correct previous food since they are not necessarily alphabetically ordered. 
I just need whichever other food in the grouping `!=` the `new_food`. How can I get this?

Can I avoid using a subquery or is that inevitable? The database says I can't nest aggregate functions and it is frustrating.

Here is my sqlfiddle so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a2a46/1

EDIT: I've solved this with a subquery here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dd8b9/12 but can we do better? Surely there must be a way of doing this comparison easily within the grouping no?

Comment: you have in sample previous based on group ordered descending, and in query - not. which you want?..

Comment: Ordering doesn't matter - thanks!

Comment: you don't have a subquery here. and if you dont rely on `max()` then you reply on what defining the order in the group?.. physical order of rows changes on updates

Comment: My central question is how can I make this != comparison within the group?

Comment: well you - you do it ok with aggregation function `max()`. you can use any other aggregation here - that's why I ask about the order inside the group. and what is wrong with that != comparison?..

Comment: Because it doesn't select the correct ones. I can't compare within the max(case when...) statement. Can you solve this?

Comment: "I just need whichever other food in the grouping != the new_food" - your sample and your query fit this definition. yet give different result. please elaborate the post to consist clear wanted sample that reconciles the rules